# How to access my site with ip address?

Tags: web-hosting

I've put my files in public_html but i can't access them with direct ip address? When i got to  my ip it displays: "If you feel you have reached this page in error, please contact the web site owner..."

I'm new to cpanel and hosting stuffs, have i missed an extra step to make it work?

Comment: That won't work because the IP address it not yours, it's the machine's. If you need a dedicated IP address, you'll have to request one from your hosting provider, and likely pay more for it.

Comment: **Questions involving web hosting control panels** are off-topic at [sf] because they [customize their systems beyond our ability to support](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8055), and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094)

Comment: (Hi, neelix!  We're doing a big web panel cleanup and your question was in the close queue.  No offense meant;  I'm sure your question was on topic in 2012 when you asked it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Simpl set - normally web servers use the domain name to distribute to different virtual hosts. As such, accessing via IP only is not working. Point.

Either give it a dedicated IP address and set it up (if necessary by hand) not to bind to a host name, or get a domain (the "right one") pointing to the Ip or use a hosts file to remap the domain name to the IP. But i things are set up to use virtual hosting servers (which is standard) then sorry, IP access does not work. The request must contain the proper host name / domain name for the web server to kno which site to serve.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, accessing your content via a non-DNS-URL is not possible.

What you have is called "shared hosting". This means that your provider has placed several customers' web sites on a single server. Thus, every web site on this server has the same ip address. The DNS names are all resolved to the same ip address.
When a web browser accesses one of these sites, he send a request containing the desired site name in the `host` value, so the web server can identify where to look for the content.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Answer (score 0):

You should probably get in touch with your host's support team for these sort of questions.

Typically, you receive an e-mail that has your cPanel account name, password, as well as something like "Temporary Webpage URL" which you can use to access your website until your DNS resolves in the form of: `http://127.0.0.1/~account`.

The "account" in above url example is your user name of cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have created DNS zones for your website. You don't need to have your domain DNS pointing to the new server, but you need to create a DNS zone to open that website with only IP on your machine. How to do that is out of the scope of your question.

You could access your website only with an IP, It doesn't matter if IP isn't dedicated. What you have to do is to specify inside your HOSTS file in your machine that IP (VPS or some other not dedicated IP). You specify  where your websites files are and that there is an IP for that domain where to go to get HTTP responses like so:

Open your HOSTS file on a unix system could you probably find it and modify it from terminal by:

```
# vi /etc/hosts
```

There add your new host e.g. for an IP 90.110.48.21 where yours website's files are. Add this line at the end of file:

```
90.110.48.21     my-domain-i-have-dns-created-on-the-server.com
```

Now you have to just open your browser and try to get this url:

```
my-domain-i-have-dns-created-on-the-server.com
```

You will get you development website files on your browser in your machine.